# I got this error when I am trying to initialise! "Property 'self.tableViewCellViewModel' not initialized at super.init call"

Tags: swift, initialization

```
protocol TableViewCellViewModelProtocol {
    var cellReference: TableViewCell { get set }
    func setUpData(element: ToDoElementModel)
}

class TableViewCellViewModel: TableViewCellViewModelProtocol {
    var cellReference: TableViewCell
    
    init(cellReference: TableViewCell) {
        self.cellReference = cellReference
    }
    
    func setUpData(element: ToDoElementModel) {
        cellReference.namelabel.text = element.title
    }
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let idCell = "idCell"
    
    var tableViewCellViewModel: TableViewCellViewModelProtocol
    
    lazy var namelabel: UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "mylabel"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) //error here!!!!
        self.tableViewCellViewModel = TableViewCellViewModel(cellReference: self)
        
        setUpView()
        setConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder) //and here
        setUpView()
        setConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setUpView() {
        self.addSubview(namelabel)
    }
    
    private func setConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            namelabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            namelabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            namelabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.7),
            namelabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
        ])
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a proper initialisation.
I am trying to pass the function "setUpData" from the ViewModel class to the second class - TableViewCell

Comment: The (first) error occurs because you have to initialize all stored properties **before** calling `super`. I know that moving the line up raises another error regarding `self`. You have to refactor your code to initialize `tableViewCellViewModel` before calling `super` and passing `self` afterwards. The other error complains that `tableViewCellViewModel` is not being initialized in `init(coder` at all.

Comment: Make it optional. Cell doesn't have view model all the time, for example when it prepared for reuse.